# Creating a trigger on SQL Server 2008 R2 to catch a record update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Using Great Plains here and one of our users keeps screwing up customer data so we want to put a trigger on the customer table and so we can find out who it is.

Anyway, I created a table called audit_RM00101 as follows:

```
DATE        nchar(10)   
CUSTNMBR    char(15)    
CUSTNAME    char(65)    
UPSZONE     char(3) 
SALSTERR    char(15)    
USERID      nchar(100)
```

I want to capture those same fields from the table I want to audit so I wrote the trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CatchCustomerRegionUpdate
ON RM00101
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @UserID VARCHAR(128)
SELECT @UserID = system_user
INSERT INTO audit_RM00101 
SELECT DATE, CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, UPSZONE, SALSTERR, @UserID FROM UPDATED
```

The trigger gets created just fine but when I try to test it by updating a customer record in Great Plains, Great Plains throws up an ugly error and the trigger doesn't get fired.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not telling us what the error is.

Comment: There isn't an `UPDATED` pseudo table in TSQL. Is this actual code, or something similar you've mocked up for the question?

Comment: Also, as others have noted, saying "there was an error", but not giving the error message is not helping those who might be able to help you.

Comment: Did not get an error creating the trigger but in Great Plains when I go to update a customer record I get some indecipherable Great Plains error.  When I delete the trigger, the GP error goes away.  This is actual code...I didn't know there was no UPDATED pseudo class, what is the correct syntax then?

Comment: @Tom: There is only `INSERTED` and `DELETED`. In the case of an update, `INSERTED` contains the new column values, and `DELETED` contains the old column values.

Comment: If you continue to receive errors from Great Plains, I recommend you add  "SET NOCOUNT ON;" on the first line after "AS"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in a trigger, you get the `DELETED` and `INSERTED` tables, there is no `UPDATED`, so replace `FROM UPDATED` with `FROM INSERTED`

also try to fix your USERID column, your `audit_RM00101.USERID` is a `nchar(100)` while `@UserID` is a `VARCHAR(128)`.

**EDIT** based on OPs comment: *Ah, so there is no way to audit when a table is updated by using a trigger?*

- **in a trigger when deleting**, `DELETED` is populated, but `INSERTED` is empty
- **in a trigger when updating**, `DELETED` is populated with the original value, and `INSERTED` is populated with the newly updated values
- **in a trigger when inserting**, `DELETED` is empty, but `INSERTED` has the newly inserted values

Comment: I'd try and suggest a suitable alternative/compromise for the `nchar(100)` vs `varchar(128)`, but I'd never realised how poorly documented [`SYSTEM_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) was...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, if you put the output of `system_user` into a sql_variant, then look at the SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY 'BaseType' and 'MaxLength', you find that it is a nvarchar(128).  As a result, the audit_RM00101.USERID and @UserID are both incorrect.

Comment: @KM - Agreed - you can discover it (although I assume thus far you've only tested when connected via windows authentication, direct connection etc), but the documentation on the method is pretty shoddy (returns `nchar`)

Comment: @HLGEM, how will it only catch one row? it does an `INSERT` of a `SELECT FROM INSERTED`, how will that miss rows.  the `SELECT @UserID = system_user` if fine also, because there can only be one user per operation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `UPDATED` in SQL Server; just `inserted` and `deleted`.
Also, it makes sense to add `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN` in the very beginning of triger's body. 
When `UPDATE` takes place, both `inserted` and `deleted` tables are not empty. You may add the following code to make sure you handle `UPDATE`, not `insert/delete`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) 
BEGIN
 -- handle update
END ;
```

It's not really important for your trigger because you specify just `FOR UPDATE`, it would be important if you had, for instance, `FOR UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE`.

Comment: Ah, so there is no way to audit when a table is updated by using a trigger?

Comment: `UPDATE` means that both `inserted` and `deleted` are not empty.

Answer (score 1):

we have only two magic tables called INSERTED and DELETED

update indirectly is a Delete statement followed by Insert statement. so you have to update the column's value which is present in INSERTED.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CatchCustomerRegionUpdate
ON RM00101
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @INSERTED INT, @DELETED INT
    SET @INSERTED = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED
    SET @DELETED = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED

    IF @INSERTED = 1 AND @DELETED = 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TABLE1
        SET COL1 = INSERTED_COL1
        WHERE IDCOL = INSERTED_IDCOL

    END

END
```